# iOS 7.1 imagePicker CameraFlashMode not indicating ON/OFF state

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, ios7.1

iOS 7.1 imagePicker CameraFlashMode not indicating ON/OFF state
I have iPhone application which overlays the camera with custom view. I have a button to switch between camera flash mode, this is the code.
self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode always displays auto mode.

```
 if ( self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn) {
    self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;

    [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashoff.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.flashButton.selected = NO;
}
else
{
    self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;

    [self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.flashButton.selected = YES;
}
NSLog(@"cameraFlashMode: %d",self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.imagePickerController.cameraFlashMode] forKey:@"cameraFlashMode"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[self.imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self.imagePickerController setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
//...
```

(in your particular case) explicitly mention:

```
[imagePickerController setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn];
```

---

If you don't then the camera defaults to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto`
and since the logic you've implemented doesn't handle this case, it remains in `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto`

Comment: @user3493845 : set a breakpoint and check if this method gets a hit

Comment: @user3493845 : so step-over instruction-wise and see how your if-else block functions

Comment: It is always going in else part.But when I am checking in log it always use to print UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto . I had  increase auto part also. so it used to hit only auto part.